# How to clear Excel data

Tags: excel

In my Excel I have like 20k files in there and different columns in column B is for dates and I have there like 19.04.2021, 29.02.2020/dsdd, text, etc and I want to have only dates there and to clear other inputs, does anyone have solution for that? And in column D I have like TEST2626, TESTMEDU, TE TEST etc and other names and I would like to clean them just to have name like test"

I tired some formulas first to go with data, but I would get info like 0

Comment: Do you just mean you'd like to remove the columns with the spare data? Or is the data inside each cell dirty? Posting sample data (both input and desired output) will help your question be clearer. Check the help section for advice on writing a clear/succint question - you'll get more effective answers, faster.

Comment: @DentonThomas like to clear them just to show dates from that column because I have like 24.06.2015 testste, then I have like dsadas/sad//da then I have dates,

Comment: Sounds like you got several different patterns and you need to clean each one of them. You'll need to code something in VBA to automate the process or you will have to do every clean manually

Comment: @DentonThomas it's xls file, and I have 20k in there, I put four as example  I have a lot of dates here, it's like C555/K-888 / 25.01.2019 that's one example then POP-555 22.10.2022 like this, and I would like somehow just to clean it, to show only dates

Comment: I the data order and delimiters are consistent, you'll need to create an appropriate formula -use the functions below. Only other option I can think of would be a regex search - as Foxfire says, it would be VBA. To be more clear w/ your samples, perhaps edit your post and use https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic]. SO is only for _programming_ questions. You might have better luck on [su] (but please read their help docs and make sure to post a clear question).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a column of data, and each cell contains a list of values:

```
19.04.2021, 29.02.2020/dsdd, text, etc
```

How you 'clean' this data is dependent upon what *actually* appears in that list.

If, as you posted, this is just comma-separated values, and your file is not yet CSV, I think you have two main options. [Here is one](https://superuser.com/questions/710125/how-to-help-excel-parse-my-csv-automatically). Another:

1. save it as a CSV file
2. re-open the file with Excel
3. Follow the Excel UI prompts - Excel will ask you how to separate out your data.

This will help a bunch, but it won't finish the job on the data you posted. Some of your delimiters are commas, others are slashes.

Next step is to separate your data by delimiters. Some tools to consider:

- TEXTSPLIT() if you have it
- a combination of FIND()/LEFT()/RIGHT()/SUBSTITUTE()/TRIM() (that will take awhile, but it will work ...)
- use PowerQuery to read and separate your data using DAX
- or, as @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns has noted ... you can do it all in VBA

Consider that your example has at least four delimiters: periods, commas, slashes, and spaces. You could search/substitute/cut/left/right in many ways.

For someone to provide a more specific answer, I expect you will need to post some sample data (a few rows should be enough), and also a sample output - what that data would look like *after* you run formulas.